# Cannot find sleep function

Tags: c++, windows

i'm new at C Programming (i learned c++) i want to create a process with windows.h

at first i just want to start my main programm that creates a process ( --> starts an other programm)

that's my code, but it doesn't really work, i removed every unnessasery line of code but "void sleep(700)" (or "sleep (700)" for testing if the windows methods work, but i get an error, that "sleep" cant be found.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

//bool ret;
//startupinfo stupinfo;
//prozess_information pro2info;
//Getstartupinfo (&stupinfo);

 //createprozess(null, "C:\\bsss10\\betriebssystemePRA1.exe", null, null, false, create_new_console, null,
 // null, &stupinfo, &pro2info);

 sleep (700);

cout<< "hello";

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Retagged to C++ as the code is not C.

Comment: hm, okay but more or less it should be c++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C (and C++) is case sensitive - `sleep` should be `Sleep`. Similar issues (and spelling) with your commented-out code.

Answer (score 3):

It should be (Note the capital S)

```
Sleep(700);
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You have simalar issues with the rest of your code:

- startupinfo should be [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- prozess_information should be PROCESS_INFORMATION
- Getstartupinfo should be GetStartupInfo
- createprozess should be CreateProcess

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `void main` should be `int main` and it should `return 0;` at the end. Then, it's "process" not "prozess", C++ is case sensitive, so you should use `CreateProcess`, and you're also missing capitalization on the other functions.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512%28VS.85%29.aspx)'s a working code sample that does what you want. (void main there too, but honestly, you should use `int main` for standard compliance). Read more about creating processes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx).